# Jest: How to test a nested object style using toHaveStyle

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I have a component in React Native that has a nested style object `shadowOffset`. However, I can't seem to test it with Jest as the test doesn't pass. What is an appropriate syntax to query this style object?

```js
// jest test - test doesn't pass
const popover = getByTestId("popover");
expect(popover).toHaveStyle({shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 6}});
```

dom output

```html
<View
  style={
    Array [
      Object {
        "elevation": 12,
        "shadowColor": "#000",
        "shadowOffset": Object {
          "height": 6,
          "width": 0,
        },
        "shadowOpacity": 0.37,
        "shadowRadius": 7.49,
      },
      undefined,
    ]
  }
  testID="popover"
>
```